# Not able to edit regional persistent disk in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Even though being an owner (role), i'm not able to edit the regional persistent disk in GCP.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cumfx.png)

Comment: Please go to `GCP Console => Compute Engine => Disks`, tick the checkbox near the disk name and then press "Show Info Panel" at the top right. Make sure your account is listed in the Info Panel and is granted sufficient permissions/roles.

Answer (score 0):

[Cloud IAM > Doc > Understanding roles > Predefined roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#predefined_roles)

To edit a disk, one would need `compute.disks.resize` or `compute.disks.update` permission.

Edit permissions are part of the following roles:
`compute.*` => Compute Admin
`compute.disks.*` => Compute Instance Admin, Compute Storage Admin
`compute.disks.resize` => Compute Instance Admin
`compute.disks.update` =>  Compute Instance Admin

Hence to edit disks the user needs one of the following roles:

- Compute Admin,
- Compute Instance Admin,
- Compute Storage Admin

Please go to `GCP Console => Compute Engine => Disks`, tick the checkbox near the disk name and then click `Show Info Panel` at the top right. Make sure the user's account is listed in the Info Panel and is granted a role from the list above.

Comment: I've added all of those roles to a user and still don't have edit permissions on regional ssd disks. Other disks can be edited without issues.